# C# metro, why can't I add a 'Run' twice in a 'Paragraph'?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Here is the example code

```
Run test_run = new Run();
test_run.Text = "TEST";

Paragraph test_paragraph = new Paragraph();

test_paragraph.Inlines.Add(test_run);
test_paragraph.Inlines.Add(test_run);

test.Blocks.Add(test_paragraph); // 'test' is a RichTextBlock
```

This code looks so simple, and seems to be alright..(in my opinion...)

However, if I run this code, the app causes an error.

I tried to find the reason, and I found that the code below causes the error

```
test_paragraph.Inlines.Add(test_run);
test_paragraph.Inlines.Add(test_run);
```

If I comment out one of the lines above, it works fine, but if I add 'Run' into a 'Paragraph' more than once, it causes an error.

I don't see any problem in this code, since the 'test_run' was not collapsed or removed.

Could anyone help me to understand this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it giving error that `Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first`?

Comment: 'Element is already the child of another element.'

Comment: I don't see 'Disconnect it first.' But looks pretty similar. How can I solve it..?

Comment: Read my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do

```
Run test_run = new Run();
test_run.Text = "TEST";

Paragraph test_paragraph = new Paragraph();

test_paragraph.Inlines.Add(test_run);

test_run = new Run();
test_run.Text = "TEST";

test_paragraph.Inlines.Add(test_run);

test.Blocks.Add(test_paragraph);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already knew how to solve this problem,, I just wanted to know,,, a kind of 'workaround' to make my original code work. without reassigning a new paragraph.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user3555952: Paragraph is only instantiated once. Its the `Run` that has been added again.